# Terraform Route53 record delay for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, terraform

I am creating EC2 instances but when I add a Route53 record it takes up to 60 seconds for the DNS to replicate and get recognised.

```
resource "aws_instance" "zk-host" {
  ami               = "ami-30041c53"  # Amazon Linux Image
  count             = "${var.count}"
  associate_public_ip_address = false

  connection {
    user = "ec2-user"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      ... install things here...
      #"sudo service zookeeper-server start ... after some delay ?"
    ]
  }
}

// Make a DNS entry for each host while we're here.
resource "aws_route53_record" "route53-record-zk" {
  zone_id = "${var.route53-zone-id}"
  count   = "${var.count}"
  name    = "${var.host-name-prefix}${count.index}.dwh.local"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "30"

  records = [
    "${element(aws_instance.zk-host.*.private_ip, count.index)}"
  ]
}
```

The problem is, I am using the remote-exec provisioner to start services in my EC2 instance that rely on DNS to find its peers.

I don't seem to be able to configure the DNS entry before I create the EC2 instance.

Is there a way I can post-process my EC2 instance and start the services later? Or is there a technique to delay the service start until the DNS entries exist?

Comment: You need add the wrapper script in remote-exec, such as `sleep 120`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but doesnt work. The problem seems to be the interdependency on *aws_route53_record*. It depends on the aws_instance to get its IP. Addling a sleep just delays the completion of the aws_instance. I think I would need to fork it in the background somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`null_resource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) to hack around this so you separate the provisioner from the instance resource.

In your case it would look something like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "zk-host" {
  ami               = "ami-30041c53"  # Amazon Linux Image
  count             = "${var.count}"
  associate_public_ip_address = false
}

// Make a DNS entry for each host while we're here.
resource "aws_route53_record" "route53-record-zk" {
  zone_id = "${var.route53-zone-id}"
  count   = "${var.count}"
  name    = "${var.host-name-prefix}${count.index}.dwh.local"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "30"

  records = [
    "${element(aws_instance.zk-host.*.private_ip, count.index)}"
  ]
}

resource "null_resource" "zk-host_provisioning" {
  count = "${var.count}"

  connection {
    user = "ec2-user"
    host = "${element(aws_instance.zk-host.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      ... install things here...
      #"sudo service zookeeper-server start ... after some delay ?"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd be slightly wary of relying on DNS discovery here though because it limits your options when it comes to things like running in an autoscaling group (short of the instances working out their own DNS record and provisioning it on start up) so you might want to consider other options for service discovery inside the Zookeeper cluster. [This blog post](http://www.paulstack.co.uk/blog/2016/01/15/building-an-autodiscovering-apache-zookeeper-cluster-in-aws-using-packer-ansible-and-terraform) suggests that you can use S3 to provide a list of all nodes but you probably want to ask another question about that.

Comment: Thanks for that. Dont worry, we'll tidy this all up properly when we move out of a POC and package this up for production and other environments. This is really helpful though and helps keep us moving forward. Cheers.